# syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set no=1460
while ("$no">0)
if [$no>900]; then
 set m=3
else if ["$no">450 && "$no"<901]; then
 set  m=2
else
 set m=1
fi
mv *$no.bin test/abc-$m-$no.bin
set no =$no-1
end
```

I'm trying to rename 1460 files using a csh script, but I get a syntax error "syntax error: unexpected end of file" 
I'm on `tcsh` shell.
I've tried both `fi` and `end` to end the `if` condition. I get the same error.

Comment: Try _endif_ instead of _fi_? I'm a beginner too. Make sure you check this [amazing document](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#execution-control).

Comment: There's no point whatsoever trying to learn csh in this millennium. Your system, if it is less than 20 years old will have a POSIX shell, at least a Bourne-like shell if it's less than 30 years old. Use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search reveals that your `IF` statement syntax is probably incorrect. You may be mixing syntax from another shell.

```
if ( $no > 900 ) then
  set m=3
else if ( $no > 450 && $no < 901)
  set m=2
else
  set m=1
endif
```

http://beefchunk.com/documentation/tips/unix_tips_and_tricks/node40.html